# Nemo - Custom Places for "Move to"?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, file-manager

How can I add custom places to the "Copy to" and "Move to" option of the Nemo file manager (see picture below)? I have some special folders reserved for pdf files and I like to use the ease to move files into them via the respective options. How can I add those to the menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the answer myself. Here it is:
You can simply **drag and drop** *a folder into the sidebar*.
This will make it become a "Bookmark" and show-up as a place.

It is as simple as that, but I find poorly documented.